# Use of blocks in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
const char *sentence = "He was not in the cab at the time.";

printf("\"%s\" has %d spaces\n", sentence, (int) ^ {
    int i = 0;
     int countSpaces = 0;

    while (sentence[i] != '\0') {
        if (sentence[i] == 0x20) {
            countSpaces++;
        }
        i++;
    }    
    return countSpaces;
});
```

This code simply counts the white space in a string, but for some reason it says 1606416608 spaces rather than 8. I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong, so thanks for any help!

Comment: While Jesse has answered your technical question, the better question is why in the world you would structure your code this way? Just perform the calculation to compute a value and then pass that value into `printf()`. Don't use blocks here. They only make the code worse.

Comment: What @KenThomases said;  you are far *far* better off calculating the # of spaces first, then using that variable in the printf, no block needed.  While blocks are wonderfully useful, this isn't a situation where they should be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're passing the actual block to `printf`, not the result of the block. Instead, try

```
const char *sentence = "He was not in the cab at the time.";

printf("\"%s\" has %d spaces\n", sentence, (int) ^ {
    int i = 0;
    int countSpaces = 0;

    while (sentence[i] != '\0') {
        if (sentence[i] == 0x20) {
            countSpaces++;
        }
        i++;
    }    
    return countSpaces;
}()); // <-- note the extra parentheses here, indicating that you're calling the block
```

Comment: Wow, I never would have guessed that -- you just saved me hours of time! Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: More specifically, blocks are objects, and a block expression evaluates to a pointer to the block object. He is casting the pointer into an integer.

Comment: @newacct, no, that's not what's happening. The parentheses *after* the block definition cause the block to be invoked.

Comment: Oh, I was talking about the OP's code, as a clarification to "passing the actual block".